# Created a button to delete all table records

Tags: java, android, database

I have tried to created a button to delete the whole table records but I got this error message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method deleteAll(View) in the activity class com.example.android.ch2.user for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'b_delete'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
Any ideas that really helpful. Thanks

XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.ch2.user">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View User"
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:id="@+id/b_delete"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="deleteAll"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.android.ch2;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


public class user extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "reg_info";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);


    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void deleteAll()
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    db.execSQL("delete * from "+ TABLE_NAME);

    db.close();
}}
```

JavaHelper

```
package com.example.android.ch2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version = 1;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"   ("+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_FOOD+" TEXT);";
public DatabaseOperations(Context context){
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d ("Database operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Table created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void putInformation (DatabaseOperations dop, String name,String email,String food){

SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_FOOD, food);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d ("Database operations", "One raw inserted");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature should be `public void deleteAll(View view)`

**Edit**

Ok, so why don't we try this:

```
public void deleteAll(View view) {
    DatabaseOperations helper = new DatabaseOperations(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: @Android777 doesn't work. I gave up. Here is my all work if you like to see it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j1uq8xax8fqqhvg/AADHu7xALt_CGmdqjVbkAWDna?dl=0

Comment: @AbuMohanad hey, don't give up. I promise you to have a look at the whole project on Thursday-Friday, if it won't get resolved by that time, and tell you what is wrong there.

Comment: @Android777 I appreciate your time and kindness. I have many assignments to do. I really like to learn about Android but I don't have time. I spent over 12 hours just in this case and I have to look to other things. My professor doesn't know anything about and he says "you are in your own because I never learned anything about Android"

Comment: @AbuMohanad hey, I had a little time today to have a look at the app. What I did is deleted "*" from the delete query, that seems to be a peculiarity of SQLite syntax, and from my perspective, not looking to deep into the app's logic, it works fine - in the debug mode I can observe it inserts and removes records in the database. Please check if it works on your machine. Answer updated.

Comment: @Android777 it doesn't work too :(  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "*": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: delete * from reg_info
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)

Comment: @AbuMohanad well, that's why I deleted "*" from the code, as I said, you can see it in my answer. Just change it in your code, I cannot fix it in your dropbox :)

Comment: @Android777 I already deleted but when I run it, it shows me that message. I know that is strange and I am almost break my laptop :)

Comment: @Android777 I'm curios to know why it doesn't work you can download the file from here http://ge.tt/8Zy987E2/v/0?c

Comment: @AbuMohanad ok, this time there was no " " between `FROM` and the table name. Should be `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME);`

Comment: @Android777 I copied it and pasted and it still doesn't work. Process: com.example.android.ch2, PID: 2147
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(

Comment: @AbuMohanad man, that's just impossible. Several times I made your versions work, last time you copied my code incorrectly (forgotten space after `FROM`)(no offense). This time I haven't changed a single character in your code you'd uploaded except for that missing space symbol. It just *must* work. Edit: btw, that exception, is it still for the same button/method? Because of course I did look over the whole code and potential errors in them, just that previous problem.

Comment: @Android777 here is my code `public void deleteAll(View view) {
        DatabaseOperations helper = new DatabaseOperations(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();`

Comment: @Android777 sorry for that. I have a macbook and I always put it on sleep. There was a glitch on my Android Studio that made all that errors. I restarted and now it works. Thank you for all your time.